# Round float to 2 decimal places in C language?

Tags: c, rounding, precision

```
   float number = 123.8798831;
   
   number=(floorf((number + number * 0.1) * 100.0)) / 100.0;
   
   printf("number = %f",number);
```

I want to get `number = 136.25`

But the compiler shows me `number = 136.259995`

I know that I can write like this `printf("number = %.2f",number)` ,but I need the number itself for further operation.It is necessary that the number be stored in a variable as `number = 136.25`

Comment: Why do you need 2 decimal places? Are you dealing with money? In that case, calculate in cents (as long integers) and do the trickery when you need to represent the value.

Comment: Yes, I work with money, but I need to multiply the current account by 0.1% each time and round it to 2 decimal places.

Comment: If you are working with currency, `123.8798831;` is a bad place to start... While that may have come from some other calculation, the rounding (or truncation) should (probably) be done **BEFORE** trying to add 10% (and AFTER, too...) If you want the numbers to make sense the way people think about currency, then either use an integer type (work in pennies internally) or round, round, round... That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other comments/answers that using floating point numbers for money is usually not a good idea, not all numbers can be stored exactly. Basically, when you use floating point numbers, you sacrifice exactness for being able to storage very large and very small numbers and being able to store decimals. You don't want to sacrifice exactness when dealing with real money, but I think this is a student project, and no actual money is being calculated, so I wrote the small program to show one way of doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double number, percent_interest, interest, result, rounded_result;

    number = 123.8798831;
    percent_interest = 0.1;
    interest = (number * percent_interest)/100; //Calculate interest of interest_rate percent.
    result = number + interest;
    rounded_result = floor(result * 100) / 100;


    printf("number=%f, percent_interest=%f, interest=%f, result=%f, rounded_result=%f\n", number, percent_interest, interest, result, rounded_result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, I use `double` instead `float`, because `double` has more precession and floating point constants are of type `double` not `float`. The code in your question should give you a warning because in

```
float number = 123.8798831;
```

123.8798831 is of type `double` and has to be converted to `float` (possibly losing precession in the process).

You should also notice that my program calculates interest at .1% (like you say you want to do) unlike the code in your question which calculates interest at 10%. Your code multiplies by 0.1 which is 10/100 or 10%.

Answer (score 2):

> It is necessary that the number be stored in a variable as number = 136.25

But that would be the incorrect result. The precise result of `number + number * 0.1` is 136.26787141. When you round that downwards to 2 decimal places, the number that you would get is 136.26, and not 136.25.

However, there is no way to store 136.26 in a float because it simply isn't a representable value (on your system). Best you can get is a value that is very close to it. You have successfully produced a floating point number that is very close to 136.26. If you cannot accept the slight error in the value, then you shouldn't be using finite precision floating point arithmetic.

If you wish to print the value of a floating point number up to limited number of decimals, you must understand that not all values can be represented by floating point numbers, and that you must use `%.2f` to get desired output.

> Round float to 2 decimal places in C language?

Just like you did:

- multiply with 100
- round
- divide by 100

Comment: I work with money, I need to multiply the current account money by 0.1% each time and round it to 2 decimal places.

Comment: If you work with money, consider using an integer type to represent the value. Work with values in cents. Divide by 100 to get dollars, you already have the cents. Using floating point for money is highly discouraged. Banks are finicky about losing pennies here and there. `int64_t` gives you `9.2234e+18` cents or `9.2234e+16` dollars. Enough to represent the value of Earth with. If that's not enough, use a big-numbers library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function you can use for rounding to x number of decimals.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>

double dround(double number, int dp)
{
    int charsNeeded = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*f", dp, number);
    char *buffer = malloc(charsNeeded);
    snprintf(buffer, charsNeeded, "%.*f", dp, number);
    double result = atof(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return result;
}

int main()
{

  float number = 37.777779;
  number = dround(number,2);

  printf("Number is %f\n",number);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply using `char buffer[32];` suffice and eliminate the need to allocate and free? (though nice to see the `snprintf (NULL, 0 ...)` trick) Also, what do you anticipate the output being. Kinda hard to see how `37.779999` is an improvement over `37.777779` or am I missing something?